# Monitor and Terminate Python script based on system resource use

Tags: python, resources, monitoring, terminate

What is the "right" or "best" way to monitor the system resources a python script is using and terminate it if the resource use exceeds some predetermined values. In my case memory usage is of concern. I am not asking how to measure the system resource use although I am open to suggestions.

As a simple example, let's assume I have a function that finds prime numbers less than some large number and adds them to a list based on some condition. I don't know ahead of time how many prime numbers will satisfy the condition so I what to be sure to terminate the function if I use up to much system memory (8gb lets say).
I know that there are ways to monitor the size of python objects. What I don't know is the proper way to monitor the size of the list and exit is to just include a size test in the prime function loop and exit if it exceeds 8gb or if there is an "external" (by external I mean external to the loop but still within or part of the python script) way to monitor and exit.

In my case I am running on a mac but am asking the question in general.

Comment: Isn't this called "Design"?  Why not design an algorithm that uses minimal memory?  I'm not sure I understand how this use case differs from design.  Can you clarify why you didn't design the algorithm to minimize memory use?

Comment: @S.Lott: I am trying to ask a general question. I my actual use case, I am not sure how large my list will get or how long the experiment will run. I expect it to take a few days to run as the iterator that I am selecting numbers from is large. Sometimes even a good algorithm has an undetermined run time and memory usage until actually run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix-like system, a useful "external" way to monitor any process is the [ulimit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ulimit) command (you don't clarify whether you want instead to run in Windows, where `ulimit` doesn't exist and other approaches may, but I don't know them;-).

If you're thinking about performing such controls inside your own Python programs, just change the function in question to check the size of each object it's appending to the list (and keep a running total) and return when the running total reaches or exceeds a threshold (which you could pass as an extra parameter to the function in question).

**Edit**: the OP has clarified in a comment that they want the monitoring in the very worst place it could possibly be placed -- in the previous paragraphs, I mentioned how it's easy outside of the process, easy inside the function, but the OP wants it "smack in the middle";-).

Least-bad way is probably with a "watchdog thread" -- a separate daemon thread in an infinite loop which, every `X` seconds, checks the process's resource consumption (e.g. with [resource.getrusage](http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html?highlight=getrusag#resource.getrusage), if on Unix-like machines -- again, if on Windows, something else is needed instead) and, if that consumption exceeds the desired limits, attempts to kill the main thread with [thread.interrupt_main](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html?highlight=interrupt_main#thread.interrupt_main).  Of course, this is fail from foolproof: the periodicity `X` (like in all cases of "polling") must be low enough to stop a runaway process in the meantime, but high enough to not slow the process down to a crawl.  Plus, the main thread (the only one that can be interrupted like this) might be blocking exceptions (in which case the watchdog thread might perhaps try with "signals to this very process" of growing severity, all the way up to `SIGKILL`, the killer-signal that can never be blocked or intercepted).

So, this intermediate approach is a lot more work than the `ulimit` command, is more fragile, and has no substantial added value.  But, if you want to put the monitoring "inside the process but outside the resource-consuming function", with no advantages, lots of work, and the other disadvantages I've mentioned, this is the way to do it.

Comment: (by external I mean external to the loop but still within or part of the python script)

Comment: @Vincent, the very worst place you could possibly place it -- I mentioned how it's easy outside of the process, easy inside the function, but you want it smack in the middle;-).  OK, let me edit the A to mention a possibility.

Comment: I must be very unclear, I want it in the best place just as long as it will terminate itself. In loop or out of loop. I just don't know the reasons for choosing a "watchdog thread" over any other. Thanks for your post

Comment: @Vincent, "the best place" is outside of the Python process (by setting the process's limits with `ulimit`) as per my A's 1st paragraph, second best is in the function as per its 2nd paragraph; a "watchdog thread" is the least bad of the bad alternatives left if you want the check in neither of the spots I already explained, and I explain that in the 4th paragraph as edited.  As you don't think my answer's good, you must have in mind something else yet, but we're running out of places to put monitoring functionality!-)

Answer (score 2):

[`resource.getrusage()`](http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html#resource.getrusage) (in particular `ru_idrss`) can give you the resource usage of the current `python` interpreter, which you can use as a sentinel to stop processing.